# Elements in Binary Search Tree not showing

Tags: java, data-structures

After inserting all the elements, still i'm not seeing the tree....i don't understand what's wrong. There is no compile time error.

```
public boolean insert(int data) {
        getNewNode(root, data);
        return true;
    }

    private Node getNewNode(Node pointer, int data) {

        if(pointer == null) {
            pointer = new Node();
            pointer.data = data;
            return pointer;
        }
        else if(data < pointer.data) 
            pointer.lchild = getNewNode(pointer.lchild, data);
        else if(data > pointer.data)
            pointer.rchild = getNewNode(pointer.rchild, data);
        return pointer;
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I'm not seeing the tree"? How are you trying to see it?

Comment: You're code is a bit weird. For example you call "getNewNode" but don't assign the return value and do nothing with it. Could you please post a minimal complete example of what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call getNewNode to construct root if none exists, but do not assign the new node to root once you have returned it from getNewNode. Therefore, root will always be null.

Comment: unless it is already initialized somewhere else.... which we can't know [:-(

Comment: Nice catch; if root is already initialized then the error may be in the printing code.

Comment: Thanks Avi....i have set the new root = getNewNode...and it works....tx